# ruby on rails Instantiating inside a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, model, instance

I'm somehow newly intermediate(:D ) in rails and i'm starting to tackle more complex project that require multiple class and interaction with my model and i'm kind of lost in how to design/order my code.

I have a product_table and a product_details_table.

Every time a product is created an image is uploaded with it.

In the class Product , i have created a few methods that populate virtual attributes for that product related to that image ( size , etc. ).
This is all working with paperclip callback after upload.

My issue is that from that image size i would like to automatically generate attributes values in my product_details table.

```
Product_details.new(product_id:current_product_id(**is it self.id here?**),size:product.virtual_attribut_size,x:virtual_attribut_x)
```

How would you do that ?

I would have done it in my controller the thing is it has to been done automatically after the file upload and not before and i don't know how to do that.

If i do it in my model i'm guessing it can work ( as a normal class ) but is that the way to do it ?

Thanks to those who try to help

edit :

Basically my Product model would look like this :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def image_to_inch
    #return "30x30" (in inch) for an image uploaded in pixel (divide      the number of pixel by 300dpi to get a good quality print )
  end
  def image_printable_size
    #use previous method result to output an array of all printable size from a list of predifined sizes. example : 30x30 can be printed in 30x30,20x20,10x10 but not 40x40.
    #output ["30x30","20x20","10x10"]
  end

##Here i should iterate over the array and create a product_details line for that product for each size :

   ## simplified version of what i was going for and that look really really ugly :
  ["30x30","20x20","10x10"].each do |size|
    ProductDetail.create!(product_id:self.id,size:size)
  end
end
```

i've left out the callbacks,validation,etc. so that it's easier to read.

Comment: What is the association between Product and ProductDetail?

Comment: `class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_details'

'class ProductDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements aren't clear, but here's some strategy tips.

1. Use before_save or after_save callbacks to automate code.
2. Use attr_accessor variables to hold temporary objects which are used by before_save and after_save callbacks
3. Make simple methods to do simple things.  Remember that you can write your own custom getter and setter methods.

So, your approach could be something like this: i'm guessing at your schema so don't get too hung up on the details.

```
class Product
  has_one :product_detail
  after_save :update_product_details

  def update_product_detail
    product_detail = self.product_detail || self.product_detail.build
    if self.image
      product_detail.update_from_image(self.image)
    end
    product.save
  end

class ProductDetail
  belongs_to :product

  def update_from_image(image)
    self.size = image.size
    #... any other settings taken from the image
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. You teached me ".build" that look awesome.

My issue is that Product has many product details. Each row is basically the products size,print_size(it's painting),eshopprice,artist comission(inputed at creation of the product by user, for each size comission is different )

Comment: Like i said, you can adapt my approach for the details of your own schema.

Comment: So i can use self.v_attributs into my Product model to create a new row for the product self ?

`ProductDetail.create!(product_id:self.id,size:self.size)`

I guess i don't really get why do you use a method from ProductDetail model inside the Product Model instead of passing it directly as an argument. like my create! above.

thanks alot for the help anyway

Comment: If you call, inside a product instance, "self.product_details.build" this will set up the association, ie set the "product_id" field in the new product_detail object.  it also won't save it until the Product is saved (this is what "build" does - it's like "make the new object but don't save it till I am saved").  When it comes to determining which aspects of the image are saved into the new product_detail object, the responsibility for the logic for that should be held in the ProductDetail class, not the Product class.  Each class should know as little as possible about other classes' logic.